# Counterexamples / Special case of a Second Derivative Test

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

[image]

The statement of the Second Derivative Test is shown above. And I got one question when I saw that statement. Does there exist a function such that the second derivative of $f$ is continuous "at" $c$, but not continuous "near" $c$ and satisfies the second derivative test above? If it doesn't exist, then why?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you don't need the continuity assumption at all, so the following statement is also true:

> **Theorem.**
>
> Let $f:I\to \Bbb{R}$ be a function defined on an open interval $I$, and let $c\in I$. If $f''(c)$ exists, then the following assertions are true:
>
> - If $f'(c) = 0$ and $f''(c)>0$ then $f$ has a local minimum at $c$
> - If $f'(c) = 0$ and $f''(c)<0$ then $f$ has a local maximum at $c$.

Comment: Then, what can be the condition which is equivalent with the existence of the second derivative? If the second derivative exists for every point in the interval, should it be continuous near $c$?

Comment: @19017김범준 the second derivative exists if it exists, so just use the definition, I'm not sure what else I can say about that. Even if $f''(x)$ exists at every point $x\in I$, there is still no guarantee that $f''$ is continuous at $c$. For example, let $f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ be defined as $f(x) = x^4\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ if $x\neq 0$, and defined $f(0)=0$. Then, $f''(x)$ exists at every point of $\Bbb{R}$, however $f''$ is not continuous at $0$.